# groovy date plus giving wrong dates

Tags: groovy, time, dateadd

I am trying to generate a random date and then add 5 number of days to it. it works fine most of the times but when the new date goes into next year, the result is actually going back to the beginning of the same year. Not sure why.. here is my code

```
Date today = new Date();
def endRange = 1500
def randomInterval = new Random().nextInt(endRange)
startDate = today.plus(randomInterval)
endDate= startDate.plus(5)
```

I run this in loop for 1000 times and 18 out of those are either resetting back to the same year or adding one year. not sure why. Below are two example output results

```
startdate         enddate
2022-12-27   -- > 2022-01-01
2020-12-26  -- >  2021-12-31
```

appreciate any help on this

// update

after a bit digging, this is happening after I change the date format to "YYYY-MM-dd" before writing to excel as that is the format I need. and it is consistently happening to any date that gets rolled over to next year after adding 5 days.

```
Date today = new Date();
def minStart = today+5 //diff_currentDt_startDt
def endRange = 1500
def randomInterval = new Random().nextInt(endRange)
startDate = today.plus(randomInterval)
endDate= startDate.plus(diff_startDt_endDt)
// after this I format them and then write to excel
def startDate1=startDate.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
def endDate1=endDate.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
Label label1= new Label(0, i, startDate1)
sheet.addCell(label1)
Label label2= new Label(1, i, endDate1);
sheet.addCell(label2);
```

again checking further, somehow the format is messing it up. Below are the dates before and after formatting

```
Tue Dec 24 19:31:02 EST 2019  //startdate
2019-12-24  // startdate in YYYY-MM-dd format
Sun Dec 29 19:31:02 EST 2019  // enddate (startdate +5)
2020-12-29 // enddate in YYYY-MM-dd format
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this happen every time the startDate is 27/12/.. or greater? I've run your 1000 test a few times & haven't replicated you results, what are your underlying date settings?

Comment: Is the error random, or can you replicate it?  If you can replicate it, then please add the code to the question, that shows the actual problem.

Comment: first to answer both your questions, after a bit digging this is happening after I format the dates with ".format('YYYY-MM-dd') before writing to excel because that is the format I need it to be. Updating the main question.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the "YYYY" in .format('YYYY-MM-dd') is causing issue its fixed after changing it to "yyyy" in .format('yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: `YYYY` is the full _week year_, while `yyyy` is the full calendar year. Uppercase is probably not what anyone wants. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year